# Find det A if A is 3 × 3 and det(2A) = 6.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

So i was given this question.

Find det A if A is 3 × 3 and det(2A) = 6.

Trying to solve this i tried to use the fact that

If A is an n × n matrix, then $det(uA)$ = $u^ndetA$ for any number u.

So for this case if i was given the det(uA) would i just divide the 2, so the answer is 3?

Comment: $2^3=8$$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \         $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : If $A$ is a $3\times 3$-matrix, then $det(2A)=8\ det(A)$

Comment: Is the n the matrix, so it would be 2^3?

Comment: Yes.  Notice that the rule reads, "If $A$ is an $\mathbf{n \times n}$ matrix..."