# Find $\det(2A^2)$ if $A$ is 3 × 3 and $\det(A) = 4$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I attempted to solve this problem using basic determinant properties

Since $A$ is a 3x3 matrix, I know that $\det(2A) = 2^3\times4 = 32$.

However, I'm unsure of how to find $\det(2A^2)$. I haven't learned to use a property for $\det(A^2)$ to solve determinants

Comment: Hint: in general, $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$.

Comment: [Follow the example given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500449/find-det-a-if-a-is-3-%c3%97-3-and-det2a-6?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Did you know that $\det (AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$? This is the property you will require.

You can then say $\det(2A^2)=\det (2A\times A)$, and apply the above.

Comment: Using this property, I got det(2A^2) = 128

Comment: @jahiranderson Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT 2**: the determinant is a $n$-multilinear application, thus, in your case $\det(2A^2)=2^3\det (A^2)$.

The general property is the following: consider
$$
\det:\mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)\to\Bbb R
$$
then for every $A\in\mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)$ and for every $\alpha\in\Bbb R$,
$$
\det(\alpha A)=\alpha^n\det A\;.
$$

Comment: `det(2 A^2)=2^3 detA` There is a square missing on the RHS.